# In what ways can I make my character Huge without changing his form?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I want to make the largest character that I can without changing into another form.  What spells, powers, items, or otherwise can I utilize in order to achieve this goal?  Mention of size increases that can stack with other methods of increasing size would be most appreciated.  Third-party material is allowed.

Comment: Do you have any limitations on class? Do you just want benefits of "large" size? Do you want to be forever this big?

Comment: I'm thinking about going with Barbarian, and I am looking to acquire large size for both its benefits and for flavor.  I am playing as a proto-type Warforged Titan, and the prospect of ever-increasing size categories seems appealing to me.  If there are ways for my character to be forever big, I'd like to know about them, too.  I think my GM is willing to work with me in one way or another (he specifically asked for my character to try to be Large, as the Warforged race is a Medium race by default).

Comment: Are you limited by race, or will any playable race do?

Comment: The race I am looking at is Warforged.  So, there probably is no special size modification abilities based on race going for me here.

Comment: Food. Lots of food. Especially carbs and protein. Dumplings in chicken broth work best. Favored by sumo wrestlers. :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[As TechImp points out](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/48646/10979), one increase can be gained via (permanencied) [*enlarge person*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/enlarge-person). This leads to the problem that the spell states:

> Multiple magical effects that increase size do not stack.

Meaning we now need to find a second, nonmagical effect to increase in size. In this case, we will look for abilities that are neither spells nor spell-like abilities.

### [Synthesist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/archetypes/paizo---summoner-archetypes/synthesist) [Summoner](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner) (8th or 13th)

> **Fused Eidolon**
> A synthesist summons the essence of a powerful outsider to meld with his own being. The synthesist wears the eidolon like translucent, living armor. The eidolon mimics all of the synthesist’s movements, and the synthesist perceives through the eidolon’s senses and speaks through its voice, as the two are now one creature.

This allows you to summon your own personal translucent Gundam! (Remember, the Eidolon looks like the Summoner wants it to look like) Also, Fused Eidolon has no type (Sp, Ex, Su), so we can assume that it is non-magical (by RAW).

Take the [Large](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/eidolons#TOC-Large-Ex-) Evolution and combine it with *enlarge person* to become huge.

> **Large**
> An eidolon grows in size, becoming Large. [...] The summoner must be at least 8th level before selecting this evolution. [...]
> If 6 additional evolution points are spent, the eidolon instead becomes Huge. [...] The summoner must be at least 13th level before selecting this option.

Or just become huge directly at 13th level, with the option for Gargantuan...

This works as long as your Eidolon is alive, which is as long as you are conscious, due to Life Link.

### [Gifted Blade](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/classes/soulknife/archetypes/dreamscarred-press/gifted-blade) or [Psychic Warrior](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/classes/psychic-warrior) (7th)

You can also use the 1st level psionic power [*Expansion*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers/e/expansion)

> This power causes instant growth, doubling your height, length, and width and multiplying your weight by 8. This increase changes your size category to the next larger one. [...]
> If you spend 6 additional power points, this power increases your size by two size categories instead of one. [...]

You need to have a Manifester level of 7th to use 7 power points on one ability.
Note that you can not combine this with any other method, since the power states:

> Multiple effects that increase size do not stack, which means (among other things) that you can’t use a second manifestation of this power to further expand yourself.

The duration is the same as for *enlarge person*, 1min/lvl.

Comment: Eww synthesis summoner =P. Hehe you're not wrong on that but its just one of those archetypes that is the bane of GMs. And rules. And setting the crazy bar even higher ^_^

Comment: I recall that the major difference between (Su) and (Ex) abilities is that one shuts off in a dead magic zone. Am I misremembering the magicalness of supernatural abilities?

Comment: -1: Supernatural abilities are most certainly magical.

Comment: Well, @MatthewNajmon appears to be right regarding the Bloodrager bloodline.  Still, this answer provides, perhaps, the only two ways to become Huge without changing ones form.

Comment: @MatthewNajmon You are most correct. I guess I got confused with how much Su is different from Spells or Sp. "Supernatural abilities are magical but not spell-like." It's even right there in the description :) I removed the Bloodrager option from the answer, since it doesn't actually work.

Comment: The [*harrow deck of many things*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/artifacts/minor-artifacts/deck-of-many-things-harrow) card The Mountain Man *instantaneously* increases by 1 the drawer's size category with no further effects. It's possible--yet highly unlikely unless one's [stacking the *deck*](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/30920/8610)--to draw The Mountain Man multiple times during a session with the *harrow deck.*

Comment: Extra note about Psychic Expansion is that you can _also_ use the 10 minutes / level by spending an extra 2 points. So 9 points (_at level 9_) you can become Huge for 3 hours. At higher levels, that time goes up, so while not "permanent", a higher level psychic warrior can be Huge for most of the day.

Answer (score 5):

[Expansion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers/e/expansion), the psionic counterpart to Enlarge Person, can be augmented to increase size by two categories instead of one. Starting with a Medium-size character, this will get you to Huge.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late, but for reference for others curious, the Advanced Races Compendium's Were-lion race can take feats at level 5 and 9 to make their Hybrid and full lion forms able to be large, then huge. They work as a Polymorph, so sadly no stacking RAW, though some DMs may override it. It seems that gives you +6 Str, -4Dex, +6 Nat Armor, and they typical huge changes. All-in-all, calculated out (late, so it may be off a bit) its a net gain of +1 attack, +2 AC (lost 2 DEX AC, and Huge costs 2 AC) but a total of 4 steps up on the damage chart of the FAQ. And of your DM let's you then take Snatch since there is no time limit on the forms and they are, flavorly speaking, a natural form, though Magical, you can slam an enemy and grab them in 1 attack, then throw them, and basicly be the classic movie giant monster as your allies can take advantage of your Huge distraction

Answer (score -2):

If you play as the 3rd party [awakened gargoyle](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/3rd-party-races/total-party-kill-games/awakened-gargoyle), you can say that the person who made you set your size to large (technically any size, but I wouldn't push any further than large or the GM probably won't allow it) and become a [psychic warrior](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/classes/psychic-warrior) which allows for you to grow to huge and later gargantuan.

If you want to be able to use colossal sized swords with your gargantuan sized character, look at the [Titan Fighter](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/fighter/archetypes/paizo---fighter-archetypes/titan-fighter) archetype.

Comment: Can you provide more source-links or information on where the 3rd party race and the classes involved are?

Answer (score -6):

The [Boots of the Winter Jarl](http://www.archivesofnethys.com/MagicWondrousDisplay.aspx?FinalName=Boots%20of%20the%20Winter%20Jarl) from Reign of Winter Pathfinder Adventure Path Book 3 "enable their wearer to take the form of a frost giant", which *does* change your form, but it also makes you huge for 10 min per day without having to be any particular class or such.

Comment: You should summarise the information from the link in your answer rather than providing just the link itself. If the web page 404s at some point in the future than it invalidates your answer if you don't have the relevant information summarised as part of your answer.

Comment: From the link "enable their wearer to take the form of a frost giant" but from the question "Without Changing His Form". This doesn't satisfy one of the primary requirements of the question.