# What's the largest a 1st level character can get?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization, creature-size

In the words of Tom Hanks: "I wanna be... big."

A) What is the largest size a first level character can achieve on his own? Assume potions and scrolls are allowed, but that his buddy Elminster or Gandalf can't just cast Maximized Greater Embiggen on him. (IE, only the characters resources can be used.)

B) What is the largest size a first level character can achieve on a recurring basis? Assume this means at least 3x a day, for at least 2 weeks out in the adventuring field. Again, using only the character's own resources.

Official materials, no 3rdparty or homebrewed elements. Let's say that the GM has given the character 175 GP at first level - the max of the class level amounts, regardless of what class the character has.

Comment: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48641/in-what-ways-can-i-make-my-character-huge-without-changing-his-form - similar but different in that 3rd party is allowed and any level is considered.

Answer (score 16):

**Colossal.**

A character's level is [the sum of all their class levels](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Level), and does not include racial hit dice. Since you haven't specified any limit on ECL or racial hit dice, the answer's simple: Just pick a creature that's colossal as your race (such as [Great Wyrm Gold Dragon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/dragons/dragon/metallic-gold)), take a single level of any class (let's say [commoner](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/npc-classes/commoner)), and let the game begin.

Note that your GM may shoot you if you try this.